# Asyncio running multiple asynconrous functions at once with uvicorn and fastapi

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm having some problems with running my own async functions with uvicorn (fastapi)

My goal is to be able to run the `queue manager` function, as well as the uvicorn webapp. However, it seems that my `start` function blocks the `uvicorn.run` code from running.

```py
async def queue_manager(self):
        while True:
            job = await self.queue.get()
            print(job)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def start():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(queue_manager())
    await asyncio.gather(task1)

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(server.router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(start())
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=5959)
```

In order to fix this I attempted to run `uvicorn.run` inside of my `start` function, however this results in the following error:

```py
line 35, in <module>
    asyncio.run(start())
line 17, in start
    await uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=5959)
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

```py
async def start():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(custom_instance_manager.queue_manager())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(uvicorn.run(
        "main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=5959))
    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(start())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [startup](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#startup-event) event.

```
async def queue_manager(self):
        while True:
            job = await self.queue.get()
            print(job)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)


app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(server.router)

@app.on_event('startup')
async def start():
    asyncio.create_task(queue_manager())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=5959)
```

Comment: You should hold the reference of that task, otherwise the GC can clean that up.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `uvicorn.run` you can use uvicorn server async func with fast api config

```
async def run_server():
    api = configure_fastapi()
    config = uvicorn.Config(api, port=8021, host='0.0.0.0')
    server = uvicorn.Server(config)
    await server.serve()
```